# ssh-related commands not working if nginx is running

Tags: linux, nginx, ssh

I'm facing a very weird problem: since several days ago, all ssh-related commands stuck on my linux server, including `scp`, `git clone`, `git pull`, for example:

```
➜  ~ git clone git@bitbucket.org:wong2/wx-jssdk-api.git 
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/wx-jssdk-api/.git/
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

but if I stop nginx (which is running on the same server): `/etc/init.d/nginx stop`, everything works as normal.

What could be the problem? thanks

Update:

output of `scp -v ...` https://gist.github.com/wong2/07728dc3d5f849129184da5ea34b05dc

Comment: What do you see if you log in with `ssh -v` for verbose mode?

Comment: @Halfgaar log in to what?

Comment: @wong2 any server that you have access to, the point is to see the response from _a_ SSH server when it closes the connection during the exchange identification. If nothing interesting shows up try with 2 v's: `ssh -vv ....`

Comment: @Purefan ssh from this server to other servers are ok. `scp` or `git clone` can't work

Comment: scp uses the ssh protocol. Have you checked http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer ?

Comment: @Purefan this is the log of `scp -v ...`: https://gist.github.com/wong2/07728dc3d5f849129184da5ea34b05dc

Comment: I don't readily see your problem, but on a side-note, you can update your question with relevant info after being asked. SF doesn't work like a forum where you keep pressing reply, because it's hard to read the context then.

Comment: What @Halfgaar said.

Comment: To be clear, you mean _ougoing_ SSH connections from your server that also runs that Nginx, right?

Comment: @Halfgaar yes, that's right

Comment: You can edit your question to make that more clear :). If all else fails BTW, you may want to make tcpdumps and look at it with Wireshark.